# JavaFX SceneBuilder 2 relative path exception

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i am building a javaFX app using SceneBuilder, the problem is, when i specify a relative path in the fxml file, it throws an exception on runtime:

```
null/../images/text_formal.png
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:13

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.graduation.project.fxml.manager.FXMLManager.<init>(FXMLManager.java:26)
at com.graduation.project.Main.start(Main.java:14)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or        resource not found
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

anyhow when i set the absolute path it works fine ,, what i am doing wrong ?

my fxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="427.0" prefWidth="482.0"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="com.graduation.project.main.gui.MainScreen">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="77.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="482.0" style="-fx-    background-color: #5475ba;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"     AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="77.0"     layoutY="52.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../images/text_formal.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Loading the FXMl

```
public class FXMLManager{

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
Parent root;
String stageFXMLName;


public FXMLManager(String stageFXMLName){
    try {

        this.stageFXMLName = stageFXMLName;
        this.fxmlLoader = constructFXMLLoader(stageFXMLName);
        this.root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load(getURL("/fxml/" +     stageFXMLName).openStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private FXMLLoader constructFXMLLoader(String stageFXMLName) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getURL(stageFXMLName));
    fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

    return fxmlLoader;
}


public <T> T getController(Class<T> controllerType) {

//          this.root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load(getURL("/fxml/" +     this.stageFXMLName).openStream());

        T controller = controllerType.cast(this.fxmlLoader.getController());
        return controller;
}

public URL getURL(String url) {
    return FXMLManager.class.getResource(url);
}


public Stage getStage(String title) {
    Scene scene =new Scene(this.root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
//      scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/" +     TerminalUtilsDataModel.instance.getTheme() + ".css");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle(title);
//      stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/stage_logo.png"));
    return stage;
    }

}
```

and calling with :

```
FXMLManager manager = new FXMLManager(FXMLConstants.MAIN_SCREEN);
//manager.getController(MainScreen.class).setUp();
Stage stage = manager.getStage("test");
stage.show();
```

Comment: Gluon provide a more [modern version of SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/) than the Oracle supplied SceneBuilder 2, you may wish to use the Gluon version instead.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you use to load the FXML file.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks i will try it

Comment: kindly check the edit

Comment: What is FXMLManager?  That is not a JavaFX core class.  It's pretty hard to provide advice on code that is not there.

Comment: the code of FXMLManager is above )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load from a stream, FXMLLoader does not know how to resolve relative paths because there is no concept of a relative location in relation to a stream.  Instead, in your FXMLManager [load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) the FXML from a [URL location that you already set on the FXMLLoader instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setLocation-java.net.URL-):

Don't do this:

```
this.root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load(getURL("/fxml/" + stageFXMLName).openStream());
```

Instead, do this:

```
this.root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load();
```